# django-allauth facebook login user email

Tags: facebook-login, django-allauth

I am using django all-auth with facebook login oauth2 (NOT the js sdk). When I review the new registrations like

```
select * from auth_user;
```

Some of the registrations via the fb login are missing emails in my database. My facebook app has the [email field approved](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/) so facebook should be returning the email to django.

The info is inconsistently in the `socialaccount` table

```
select id, provider, Extra_data from socialaccount_socialaccount
order by id desc;
```

returns data like this

```
272 facebook {"id": "foo", "name": "bar", "first_name": "baz", "last_name": "biz"}
239 facebook {"id": "foo", "email": "email@gmail.com", "name": "bar", "first_name": "baz", "last_name": "biz"}
```

How do I make all-auth store the email when logging in with facebook?

Answer (score -1):

In `settings.py` set configuration `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` to `True`